# How to output ImageData as a BMP image in Java

Tags: java, bmp, imagedata

How to output `ImageData` as a BMP image in Java?

I used this code:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
imageLoader.save("output.bmp", ImageLoader.TYPE_BMP, new ImageData[]{imageData});
```

But `ImageLoader.TYPE_BMP` eported an error stating that the `TYPE_BMP` could not be found.

May I ask what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

SWT's `ImageLoader` does not support saving images in BMP format directly, so
if you need to save an image in BMP, you can use Java's built-in `ImageIO` class, like:

```java
try {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("input.jpg"));
    ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("output.bmp"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I hope that helped you @xueling